# Activity isFinishing true after onPause

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to open a `AlertDialog` after opening another activity and returning but it does not get through this `if`.

**Code**

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
```

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity a;

    public MyAdapter(Activity a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // other code

        if (!((Activity) a).isFinishing()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(a, R.style.dialog);
            builder.setTitle(a.getString(R.string.dialog_share));
            builder.setView(list);
            builder.setNegativeButton(a.getString(android.R.string.cancel), null);
            dialog = builder.show();
        }

        // other code
    }
}
```

**Usecase**

- Adapter with items
- Click one item (opens activity)
- Return to first activity
- Try to open dialog (code above used in baseadapter (item in listview has buttons))
- Nope

Any ideas?

Comment: please clarify what you need and what is the error

Comment: It says on the top `isFinishing` is true. Eventhough my activity is active.

Comment: You said you wanted to open a dialog before a new activity starts.. but where is it's code.  SOrry I can't understand

Comment: No, the question says `I'm trying to open a AlertDialog after opening another activity and returning`

Answer (score -1):

Is the activity "a" passed in the constructor the activity that contains the list? If yes, when you click an item and it opens another activity, the activity a goes into the process of finishing, thus making isfinishing return true. Can you try other ways to check when user has return to activity a, like onActivityResult?

Comment: Yes, it's the "holding activity". The activity `a` is used in the baseadapter to open another activity so `a` might get inactive there? Keep in mind this is not an answer to my question but a question to my question so you should keep it in the comment section.